# How to test and adjust a website for iphone?

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari, web-deployment

I developed this [website](http://prawalekarzy.pl)

It looks fine on most browsers and OSes on PCs. It even looks nice on my HTC with Opera Mobile. Unfortunately I keep getting reports about how it displays on iphones. I don't have an iphone so here are my questions:

1. Is there an easy way to reliably check (emulate) my website on iphone (I tried sites like [this](http://iphone4simulator.com/) 
   but what this site does it opens iframe in safari trying to emulate ihopne native screen size, but the problem is somewhere else...)?
2. Any quick tips on obvious mistakes I made?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I partially found the answer. As it turned out most mobile browsers (including safari for iphone and default browser in samsung galaxy) don't support

```
{ background: transparent;}
```

So I need to provide fallback colour as described here: http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Answer (score 1):

If you have got a computer with MacOS installed (it could even be a hackintosh), you can install Xcode there and then run the iPhone simulator from it. Once you are there, you can open Safari in the simulator and enter your site URL to have a look.

I am also attaching a snapshot of the simulator with your home page.
[image]

You might try defining the viewport in your HTML:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Also, have a look at the other [meta tags available in Mobile Safari](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html).

Comment: It looks like background of the main content is missing. I have no idea why. Also scaling doesn't work at all...